# What does $(shell imlib2-config --libs) in a Makefile do?

Tags: shell, sed, makefile

I am a newbie into unix/linux world.. currently trying to run an application in my windows 7 laptop that originally built using C++ on unix/linux platform. I came across a Makefile and trying to understand what it is trying to do. Any help / guidance on what the below content of Makefile is doing is much appreciated... Thanks in advance for the help.

```
CFLAGS := -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wall -W -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -pedantic-errors $(shell imlib2-config --cflags) -O3
LDLIBS := $(shell imlib2-config --libs)
PREFIX := /usr/local
BINDIR := $(PREFIX)/bin
MANDIR := $(PREFIX)/share/man/man1
DOCDIR := $(PREFIX)/share/doc/ssocr
DOCS   := AUTHORS COPYING INSTALL THANKS
VERSION := $(shell sed -n 's/^.*VERSION.*\(".*"\).*/\1/p' defines.h)
```

followed by the regular target and dependencies...

Comment: I am specifically interested in understanding the first 2 lines and the last line.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
LDLIBS := $(shell imlib2-config --libs)
```

runs the `imlib2-config` program with the option `--libs` so as to get the correct information that should be added to the C (or C++) compilation command line so that the program being built can pick up the library (or libraries) defined by or used by `imlib2`.  The output from the program is saved in the `${LDLIBS}` (or `$(LDLIBS)`) macro.

Similarly, the first line contains:

```
$(shell imlib2-config --cflags)
```

This runs the same configuration script with the option to get the compiler flags necessary to compile the code with the `imlib2` library and headers, and the output is saved as part of the `${CFLAGS}` macro.

The VERSION line runs the `sed` script to pick up the version information from the header `defines.h` which contains a line such as `#define VERSION "1.2.3.4"` or `static const char VERSION[] = "2.3.4";` and assigns the material inside the double quotes as the value of the `make` macro `${VERSION}`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I figured that out later and also found out that imlib2-config is an unrecognized command on my windows 7. Not sure if this would be the right place to ask queries on how to get imlib2 installed or configured on windows 7.

Comment: I tried to run the basic example from enlighten... http://docs.enlightenment.org/api/imlib2/html/   but getting the "no such file or directory" message for imlib2-config command.  I had earlier unzipped imlib2 package into a folder and tried to run ./configure but got the below errors...     ./configure: line 11: $'\r': command not found
./configure: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
./configure: line 19: `elif test -n "${BASH_VERSION+set}" && (set -o posix) >/de'/null 2>&1; then

Comment: Currently looking for help to have imlib2 installed and configured correctly on my windows 7 having Cygwin. My next step would be to get the simple and advanced programs from enlighten to work...

Comment: It appears that the project home page is [Enlightenment](http://enlightenment.org/) and that the source is available from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/enlightenment/files/imlib2-src/).  It appears that `imlib2` is a small part of a much bigger project.  You can find an older version of the source at [Freecode](http://freecode.com/projects/imlib2).

Comment: Building `imlib2` is going to require a number of pre-requisites, including `pkg-config` and Freetype.  I don't have those on this machine (Mac OS X) so there may be other packages too.  I've built both those on other Macs in the not very distant past.  You'll have to go through the process yourself for the prerequisites.  Where you can find a prerequisite built by/for Cygwin, use that build.  Where you can't, you'll have to build it yourself.